# Cannot access a disposed object exception in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I am using the following code to call WCF service methods

```
MyServiceClient proxy = new MyServiceClient();
proxy.Open();
proxy.Func1();
proxy.Close();
// Some other code
proxy.Open();
proxy.Func2();

proxy.Close();
```

I get the exception while calling the 'proxy.Open()' second time but sometimes the code works. I can also use the following code shown below which works fine.

```
MyServiceClient proxy = new MyServiceClient();

proxy.Func1();

// Some other code

proxy.Func2();

proxy.Close();
```

I also want to know which is the better way of calling the functions. Which approach will give better performance ?

Comment: Maybe you just removed it to simplify, but you should be using `finally` to ensure you always close open resources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you close a connection, you can't reuse it.

You need to make a new `MyServiceClient` at that point.

```
MyServiceClient proxy = new MyServiceClient();
proxy.Open();
proxy.Func1();
proxy.Close();

// Some other code

proxy = new MyServiceClient(); // Recreate the client here
proxy.Open();
proxy.Func2();
proxy.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

WCF is one of few instance (possibly only instance) in the .NET framework where you should **NOT** use the `using` statement with a class that implements `IDisposable`. This [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx) explains the correct pattern for using service references. This also applies to `Channel` instances created from `ChannelFactory`.

Comment: Geeze Louise.  I agree, this is the ONLY place I've seen Microsoft write this up about avoid the using statement.  'System.ObjectDisposedException'   
    Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader+ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel'.    
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Use the same proxy over multiple calls

```
MyServiceClient proxy = new MyServiceClient();
proxy.Open();
proxy.Func1();

// Some other code

proxy.Func2();
proxy.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned you should worry about deterministic release of resources after calling `Close()` method, but if `Exception` occurs in `Func1,2()` methods external resources will not be released.

I suggest you to use `using` and `IDisposable` pattern, that means everytime you want to make service call use:

```
using(MyServiceClient proxy = new MyServiceClient())
{
    proxy.Func1();
}
```

which guarantees that all resources will be released even if something goes wrong within braces. Or you can do this manually with `try, finally` combination.